# My turtle's shell flakes off

Tags: reptiles, turtles

My red ear slider shell flakes off as clear flakes. What is happening, what do I need to do? I have been using cuttle bone and stepped up his basking.

Comment: I know this is the over-used cliche, but have you gotten a vet's opinion yet? Maybe it's (and I don't know much about turtle's shells or what they're made of) a calcium deficiency. I would definitely wait to get an expert opinion before strongly considering the idea, but it is possible, assuming that turtle shells consist of calcium.

Answer (score 3):

### A turtles shell

From [Mader Reptile Surgery and Medicine](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/book/9780721693279)

> A turtles shell is covered by a superficial layer of keratin shields called scutes. Both scutes and underlying bone are capable of regeneration. Turtles produce new scutes with each major growth period and retain or shed the scutes from the preceding growth period.

If your turtles shell looks healthy besides the flakes, you are likely seeing your turtle shed its scutes. With good husbandry you do not need to do anything, the scutes will come off on their own.

Comment: You could feed some carrot in stripes to help the turtle lose it's old scutes.